# What is the solution to the first Reachwater Rock puzzle

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the solution to the first Reachwater Rock puzzle, I've got the claw (hard to miss) but can't find any hints as to what the solution might be.

> Its for the quest to reforge Gauldur's amulet in the questline Forbidden Legend.

Update:
I've bruteforced the solution, see my answer, if someone can point out the hints I've missed I'll accept their answer, otherwise I'll accept my own in a few days.

Comment: I must have encountered a glitch, because I followed the quest so far, got the claws, put in the right combo and turned the claw, and the door wont open! SO frustrated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the solution on the back of the claw: open your inventory, inspect it, and rotate it around. As [you noted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35625/what-is-the-solution-to-the-first-reachwater-rock-puzzle/35626#35626), the solution is:

- Outer: Bear
- Middle: Whale
- Inner: Snake

There are a few puzzles that consist of looking at the quest item at different angles: Bethesda [seems to have been very proud of this feature](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xwboyafbwc#t=3m49s), and these quests appear to just be a means to highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

If some are looking here for the 2nd one, it's (I used bruteforce):

- Eagle
- Eagle
- Dragon

This is actually the Ivory Dragon Claw for the second door. If you look at the claw in your inventory, you will see the combination on the underside of the claw itself.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I still haven't found any hints, but I've brute forced my way through.

It is (top to bottom) Bear, Whale, Snake.

Comment: yea, did the same this with this one, nothing on all the walls seem to hit to the answer (must have missed it).

Comment: Probably, if someone points out the hints I'll accept their answer, editing the question to reflect that.